# Bad SQL grammar, Oracle : while the query is working fine in DB editor in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, oracle, jdbctemplate

I am using Oracle DB with Spring Boot Application. The query is working fine in DBeaver but not in actual application. I have copied the query from the console error message.

Query calling function:

```
  public List<UserFullNameDesignationDto> getUserFullNameDesignation(String[] userNames) {
    String queryParam = "";
    for (String uName : userNames) {
      queryParam += "'" + uName + "',";
    }
    queryParam = queryParam.substring(0, queryParam.length() - 1);
    String sql =
        "SELECT\n"
            + "\tu.USERNAME,\n"
            + "\tu.FULL_NAME,\n"
            + "\tcd.NAME \n"
            + "FROM\n"
            + "\tUSER_ENTITY u\n"
            + "LEFT JOIN CORE_DESIGNATIONS cd ON u.DESIGNATION_ID = cd.ID \n"
            + "WHERE\n"
            + "\tu.USERNAME IN ("
            + queryParam
            + ");\n";

    var rowMapper = BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(UserFullNameDesignationDto.class);
     List<UserFullNameDesignationDto> list = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rowMapper);
    System.out.println(list);
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rowMapper);
  }
```

Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT
    u.USERNAME,
    u.FULL_NAME,
    cd.NAME 
FROM
    USER_ENTITY u
LEFT JOIN CORE_DESIGNATIONS cd ON u.DESIGNATION_ID = cd.ID 
WHERE
    u.USERNAME IN ('aro_user','afo_user1','afo_user1','afo_user1','afo_user1','afo_user1');
]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
............
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

This line will be

```
'aro_user','afo_user1','afo_user1','afo_user1','afo_user1','afo_user1'
```

replaced by variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of the error is that you copied the *semicolon* in the JDBCTemplate statement (which works in SQL IDE but not in JDBC)

```
+ ");\n";
```

remove it

```
+ ")\n";
```

and it will work (or you get an other error;)

Anyway you should re-think your way of concatenation input in the SQL statement towards the usage of bind variables. There are lot of examples for binding IN list on this site.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you'll have to split values stored in that variable into rows. How? Like this:

```
SQL> with test(queryParam) as
  2  (select q'['aro_user','afo_user1','afo_user1','afo_user1','afo_user1','afo_user1']' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(queryParam, '[^,]+', 1, level) val
  4  from test
  5  connect by level <= regexp_count(queryParam, ',') + 1
  6  /

VAL
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'aro_user'
'afo_user1'
'afo_user1'
'afo_user1'
'afo_user1'
'afo_user1'

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

It means that this:

```
        + "\tu.USERNAME IN ("
        + queryParam
        + ");\n";
```

should be modified so that `queryParam` is replaced by

```
(    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (queryParam,
                                 '[^,]+',
                                 1,
                                 LEVEL) val
             FROM test
       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (queryParam, ',') + 1)
```

Comment: sorry, not understand.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? I posted an example (first code) which shows what happens when such a SELECT is executed. As I said, queryParam can't be passed as you're doing it now, but substituted by a SELECT which will "split" its values into rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> userIds = Arrays.asList("User1", "User2");

String inSql = String.join(",", Collections.nCopies(userIds.size(), "?"));

 
List<User> employees = jdbcTemplate.query(String.format("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id IN (%s)", inSql), userIds.toArray());
```

Please see, https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbctemplate-in-list for